# Using the codeigniter upload library to upload file from url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-handling

i have a file uploader in my form. I want to add a textbox in that form where a user can provide a url of a file which he wants to upload. I want to use codeigniter's default do_upload() function to upload the file so that i can use the validation function and avoid writing bulk of code again to validate that file.

I have:

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="reciept" id="reciept" />
```

I want:

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="reciept" id="reciept" />
<input type="text" class="file_url" name="reciept_url" id="reciept_url" />
```

Comment: so you want, if user provides url, for that image to be fetched and moved on to your server? if so, you should show what you have accomplished thus far. if you don't know where to start you should search stack as i'm sure someone else has tried to fetch a file from a server elsewhere. full disclosure, you probably won't be able to use codeigniters upload library as it isn't designed for this sort of thing